# Creating custom parameter group in AWS Elasticache based on default groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to create custom parameter group in AWS Elasticache.

I'd like to use a default parameter group as a base (group named default.redis5.0.cluster.on, as there is everything else I need but just one property I'd like to change), see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html for more details about default parameter groups

My basic assumption would be that I'd need to copy the default parameter group values to a Terraform resource and then just modify the only parameter I need to change. However, this would produce huge list of parameters and wouldn't seem the simplest way to do this.

If I need to do copy parameters in the `default.redis5.0.cluster.on` parameter group, then I'd need to have those in Terraform. Is there a way to import a default resource group as Terraform configuration?

Comment: Yes, you copy default one and modify.

Comment: Hi @Marcin and thanks for the comment! How the copying might be done to Terraform?

Comment: Have you tried using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_parameter_group ?

Comment: If you create parameter group according to the link from Marcin, and select redis5.0 as a "family" you will create the new group with all default parameters. So in declaration of this terraform resource you can modify only those parameters which you want to set to values different from the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to create parameter group with `family = redis5.0` that has got almost identical parameters with the default parameter group `default.redis5.0.cluster.on`.

I ended up doing JSON diff for the properties in the two parameter groups: `default.redis5.0`and `default.redis5.0.cluster.on`and there was just one parameter difference.
First, get the parameter groups as JSON:

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-parameters --cache-parameter-group-name default.redis5.0.cluster.on > default.redis5.0.cluster.on.json
aws elasticache describe-cache-parameters --cache-parameter-group-name default.redis5.0 > default.redis5.0.json
```

Then do a JSON diff for the two files to obtain parameters that are different. There was only one, `cluster-enabled` so after that it was trivial to do a custom resource group that had same parameter values as `default.redis5.0.cluster.on` this way:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" {
  name        = "cache-params"
  family      = "redis5.0"
  description = "The parameter group has same values as default parameter group default.redis5.0.cluster.on"

  parameter {
    name  = "cluster-enabled"
    value = "yes"
  }
}
```

Comment: the same goes for redis7, Ive just checked. Thanks for the answer